# mvc3 wizard like pages saving state to a database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

With using MVC3, I am hoping for a decent wizard multistep approach.  I need to have previous, next , save buttons.  Both Next and Save will be saving data to the database (more of holding staging table), yet I don't want to make the navigation a nightmare to code and manage.  I use to do this stuff with webforms, but I am hoping for a good solution with mvc3.  I really don't want sessions or cookies.  I did notice in the Apress book  "Pro ASP.NET MVC 2" by Steven Sanderson.  On page 478 he says "There are unlimited ways in which you could accomplish this....."  (regarding a wizard multistep form).

He mentions collecting and preserving data with Microsoft MVC Futures dll download, and then serializing hidden input tags.

I wanted to hear back from some experts out there on this approach vs. other approaches/solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

hope [this](http://afana.me/post/create-wizard-in-aspnet-mvc-3.aspx) post will give you some start

Comment: Nice, Thanks!  Do you think the hidden inputs from Steven Sanderson's book are not as good?

Comment: As you mentioned there are many ways of implementing this so it is upto you which suits you better but hidden inputs looks mysterious sometime to me :)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look of the simple component MVCWizard.Wizard available on NuGet. The WizardController allows you to create a wizard using partial view. There is also the AutoWizardController that renders the entire wizard in a single view. All these components operate with the session to store the model state. You can find example of MVCWizard on NuGet.

Comment: I will have to look into the MVCWizard in the near future. Thanks Max